# Finding all pairs of numbers that equals an equation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

What would be the most optimal method in c++ to discover all pairs of positive integer numbers that fit a formula. For example:

```
a^2 * b = 16;//a & b MUST be positive INT.
```

How could I find all the combinations of a and b that will fit the formula?

Edit: For more clarity, this is just an example. Really I have a^2 * b = c where c is incrementing using a for loop and I need to find every positive integer pair (a,b) that will fit the criteria of this equation.

Comment: Solve for a and put in arbitrary bs.

Comment: This question should be on the maths site.

Comment: Is it `(a^2)*b = 16` (what I understand)  or `a^(2*b) = 16`?

Comment: are there only integer solutions? otherwise there are infinite solutions!

Comment: Only positive integer solution, I have a much bigger problem but this is the simplest form I could ask it here. Technically, I have a^2 * b = c where c is incrementing via a for loop and I need to find every possibility of a and b for every c

Comment: @Ben I was just about to post that heh heh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is to find all pairs of positive integers `(a,b)` that satisfy the equation `a^2 * b = c` where `c` is also a positive integer.

From the equation, `c` is divisible by a perfect square. So first, we find all perfect squares that divide `c` evenly. Trivially, `a=1, b=c` satisfies this, so we know that every value of `c` has at least one solution. After finding every `a`, we divide `c` by each of the `a^2` to yield its corresponding `b`.

Here's the above implemented in C++:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > solve(int c) {
    std::vector<int> a;
    for (int i = 1; i * i <= c; ++i)
        if (c % (i*i) == 0) a.push_back(i);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > solutions;
    solutions.reserve(a.size());
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        const int& a = *it;
        solutions.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(a, c / (a*a)));
    }

    return solutions;
}
```

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82be9c7eb0b85504), showing solutions for `c = 7! = 5040`.

Answer (score 3):

Find the factors of c and then find the subset that use three values, two of which are the same.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, the three integer solutions are:

1. a = ±1, b = 16
2. a = ±2, b = 4
3. a = ±4, b = 1

Otherwise, there are infinite solutions. Wolfram|Alpha [gives the details](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a**2+*+b+%3D+16).

Comment: I didn't mean this one in specific. This was just an example. I mean't in any scenario with two unknown variables

Comment: Now you've changed the question in your comment. I haven't tested this, but I think it will work. For any given c, set a = floor(sqrt(c)) and b = 1. Compute a**2 * b. If it's greater than c, reduce a by 1 and try again. If it's less than c, increase b by 1 and try again. If it's equal to c, you have a solution; report it, then reduce a by 1 and increase b by 1 and try again. Stop when a becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this repeatedly, this is what I think the most efficient way to solve this problem:
1. Setup a square table, [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, ......], the length of the table depends on the maximum number you are going to deal with, anyway, you will need O(sqrt(N)) space for the lookup table.
2. divide the number into factors, for example, 16 has 5 factors (1, 2, 4, 8, 16).
3. from checking lookup table, you can find 1, 4, and 16 are in the lookup table. so there are 6 pairs, namingly, (-1 or 1)^2 * 16, (-2 or 2)^2 * 4, and (-4 or 4)^2 * 1.